# How do I stop the small spinning circles along the scanning line in QPainter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyqt, pyside2

I'm trying to rotate a line in a circle like clock's second arm. When rotating the line, I also want to draw small circles here and there inside the circle. The problem is that the small circles I drew is rotating along the line. I want these circles stay at their location and move with my code. Can someone help me?

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtOpenGL import *
from OpenGL import GL


class Helper:
    def __init__(self):
        gradient = QLinearGradient(QPointF(50, -20), QPointF(80, 20))
        gradient.setColorAt(0.0, Qt.green)
        gradient.setColorAt(1.0, Qt.blue)

        self.background = QBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0))
        self.circlePen = QPen(Qt.green)
        self.circlePen.setWidth(2)
        self.textPen = QPen(Qt.green,8,Qt.SolidLine)
        self.textFont = QFont()
        self.textFont.setPixelSize(100)

   def paint(self, painter, event, elapsed):
        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), self.background)

        painter.setPen(self.circlePen)
        painter.translate(400, 400)
        painter.drawEllipse(-250,-250,500,500)
        painter.rotate(elapsed * 0.35)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(Qt.green))
        dx = 100
        dy = 100
        for i in range(10):
           painter.drawEllipse(dx,dy,8,8)
           dx += 10
           dy += 10
        painter.save()

        painter.drawLine(0,-250,0,0)

        painter.restore()

class GLWidget(QGLWidget):
   def __init__(self, helper, parent = None):
       QGLWidget.__init__(self, QGLFormat(QGL.SampleBuffers), parent)

       self.helper = helper
       self.elapsed = 0
       self.setFixedSize(800, 800)


   def animate(self):
       self.elapsed = (self.elapsed + self.sender().interval()) % 1000
       self.repaint()

   def paintEvent(self, event):
       painter = QPainter()
       painter.begin(self)
       self.helper.paint(painter, event, self.elapsed)
       painter.end()


class Window(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
       QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

       helper = Helper()
       openGL = GLWidget(helper, self)
       openGLLabel = QLabel(self.tr("OpenGL"))
       openGLLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)

       layout = QGridLayout()
       layout.addWidget(openGL, 100, 100)
       layout.addWidget(openGLLabel, 1, 0)
       self.setLayout(layout)

       timer = QTimer(self)
       self.connect(timer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), openGL.animate)
       timer.start(1)

       self.setWindowTitle(self.tr("2D Painting on Native and OpenGL Widgets"))


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     window = Window()
     window.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

small green circles are rotating with line

[image]

small green circles are rotating with line

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEehA.png): [The results of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv1co.gif)

[The result I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txnus.gif)

[The result I want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L755W.gif)

Comment: If you want to keep the circles in a fixed position you need to draw the circles first before you rotate the painter, i.e. move the line `painter.rotate(elapsed * 0.35)` after the for loop in `paint`.

Comment: I don't mean like you said. I don't want fix position. I mean the circles can be moved by the scanning line like a radar screen. Please advice me.

Comment: So you want the circles "to stay at their location" (your words) but you also want to move the circles? It's a bit confusing to be honest. Maybe you can post a mock-up of what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. I will explain again. I want a simple radar screen. I want to draw detecting **objects** as small green circles in that screen. The **objects** will be moved when the scanning line hits them. The problem of my code is that the **objects** are rotating along the scanning line. The result of above code is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv1co.gif.

Comment: How should they be moved when the line hits them? Should they stick to the line? Something else?